# Prevent app auto-install when accidentally clicking an ad

Tags: installation, ads

I have Samsung Galaxy S20. When I get an ad on something like a game or whatever, I'm obviously going to click the X (close button) in the corner.

The problem is, sometimes I miss it because they make it so small, and when I miss and click *any* part of *any* ad, it will automatically start installing it even tho I never gave it permission.

It used to just open the app store, which was annoying but I'd prefer it to this nonsense breach of my privacy. All ads do it, not just weird ones. It did it for Candy Crush once.

I know it's not the setting "ask before download" because I've tried that.

Is there a setting or something I can do to stop it from automatically installing these apps from the ads?

Comment: Which Android device and Android version are you using? This is pure malicious behavior on part of ad playing app.

Comment: You might want to report this app on Play Store (or respective app store) if you installed it from there. This behavior is usually not permitted by the store's policy.